# Get-AzureVM Returns Nothing - Tried suggestions

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

For some reason I do not get any information when I run `Get-AzureVM` or `Get-AzureRmVm`.

I used the following to login: `Login-AzureRMAccount`.  I can see all of my subscriptions by doing `Get-AzureSubscription | select SubscriptionName`.

I am running latest version of Azure Powershell. I used Resource Manager to build my virtual machines a couple of days ago.

Comment: What happens if you run Get-AzureRmResource or Get-AzureRmResourceGroup - does Get-AzureRmContext return the right context / subscription that you expect it to If you're not getting anything being returned from Get-AzureVM/RmVM then it is either that you're not authenticated to perform the query or there isn't anything there to return (i.e. you're in the wrong subscription etc)

Comment: If you are attempting to fetch ARM resources, please use “Get-AzureRmVM” cmdlet. 


Get-AzureVM     - To fetch classic instances

Get-AzureRmVM - To fetch ARM instances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have multiple Azure subscriptions under your Azure account, you will first need to select the right subscription where your Azure Resource Manager (RM) VM resides by the following command.

```
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId <your-subscriptionId> -TenantId <your-tenantId>
```

You could see your list of subscription Ids and tenant Ids by:

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription
```

After you set the right Azure Rm Context, you should be able to get all Azure RM VM under the current subscription context by:

```
Get-AzureRmVM
```

This solution has been tested on my Azure subscription and VM using the latest **Azure PowerShell December 2015 (1.0.2).**

Hope this helps!

Comment: @RavitD On classic mode, you could use `Select-AzureSubscription "MySubscription"`

Answer (score 0):

if you choose development model is Resource Manager instead of Classic when you create a VM, you have to use the command below to list out VMs:

```
Get-AzureRmVM
```